# How many numbers made out of N digits, have the sum S? (dynamic programming)

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

So I just can't undestand how you do this. You input like **N=2 and S=3**, which means how many numbers made out of 2 digits, have their sum =3? Like 12 => 1+2= 3; for N=2 and S=3 , there are 3 numbers: 12,30,21.

I don't really know dynamic programming too well. How are you supposed to think this algorithm and the ones like this one?

Comment: How would you solve it on pen and paper?

Comment: Well, I would take for example S=10 and N=2 like 9+1 , 8+2,  7 +3 etc , but I don't know how to generalise it for any number of digits

Comment: I can show you how I made dynamically for N=2 with 2 fors, but for N>2 , I don't see how to do that, else than just increase the numbers of fors

Comment: I mean, I don't know if you have to put it in a matrix and use the values for the smaller N's

Comment: Try google.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-of-n-digit-numbers-whose-sum-of-digits-equals-to-given-sum/

Comment: Oh sorry, english is not my main language and I was doing exercises in my language, I forgot I could search it in english

Comment: Step 1: determine which digits have that sum. Step 2: create all combinations of those digits. Fill up with zero digits in all viable positions to N digits or reject if the number has more than N digits.

Comment: dynamic programming is all about STORING calculations that you have ALREADY DONE in a database and LOOKING THEM UP when you need to use their result instead of calculating it again, because the look up is computationally cheaper than the calculation. The implementation of recursive fibonacci can be sped up drastically with dynamic programming, but this problem...doesn't seem efficient to use it, maybe though...

Comment: In addition to what @PaulOgilvie wrote, if the goal is merely to count the numbers, you don't need to generate them all. You can use combinatorics. That's probably where the "dynamic programming" part is to be used.

Comment: ... For example: if you have determined that the digits 0, 0, 1, 3 sum to 4, there are 4 digits in total,  2 digits are non-zero, 1 of the digits is repeated 2 times. So the number of ways of arranging those digits is 2 * 3! / 2! (2 combinations for the 1st digit, multiplied by 3! combinations for the remaining 3 digits, divided by 2! for the repeated digit). That's 6 arrangements in total for those digits: 1003, 1030, 1300, 3001, 3010, 3100.

Answer (score 1):

Just Think about a brute force / Backtrack solution. How would you write that, which states do you need and which states can be dropped?

For this particular problem what you can do is insert a digit at a position starting from the most significant digit and move on to the next position keeping track of the sum. After inserting all the digits, if the sum is zero then you increment your answer by 1.

So the Backtrack solution will be something like this

```cpp
void f(int pos,int sum) {
    if(pos == n) {
        if(!sum) ans += 1;
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
        f(pos + 1 , sum - i);
}
```

If you can come up with the backTrack solution then already 90% of your work is done. For dynamic programming, you just have to save the states so that you will not have to recalculate a state twice. Also, think about the corner cases and base cases. In our backTrack solution, we have a bug. We should not insert 0 at the most significant digits.
Fixing all of that The code should look something like this

```cpp
#define maxN 1000
#define maxSum 1000
#define i64 long long int
#define mod 1000000007

int n;
i64 dp[maxN][maxSum];

i64 f(int pos,int sum) {
        if(sum < 0) return 0;

        if(pos == n)
        {
                if(!sum) return 1;
                return 0;
        }


        if( dp[pos][sum] != -1)
                return dp[pos][sum];

        int lo = 0;
        if(!pos)
                lo = 1;

        i64 ans = 0;
        for(int i = lo ; i < 10 ; i++)
                ans += f(pos + 1, sum - i);

        ans %= mod;


         return dp[pos][sum] = ans;
}

int main()
{
        int s;

        cin >> n >> s;

        memset(dp,-1,sizeof dp);

        cout << f(0,s) << endl;


        return 0;
}
```

The time complexity of the code is `O(maxN * maxSum * 10)`

You can find a more optimized solution online. But Once you learn a bit more about dynamic programming, You will realize that coming up with a dp solution is much faster and easier than other solutions. Happy Coding.